# apache symlink to index.html "404 Not Found"

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, symlink

I have apache2 installed on an Amazon Web Service Ubuntu instance.  If I put the ip to the instance in browser url, it successfully brings up the default apache home page.  That page is being served from /var/www/html.

Now I want to bring up my real web page which is stored at /opt/Company/Product/index.html.  I created a symlink in var/www/html that points to /opt/Company/Product, something like this:

```
ln -s /opt/Company/Product Product
```

But when I put ip/Product/index.html, I get 404 Not Found error.

In my /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf I have a VirtualHost like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/Product
   ServerName ip
   <Directory /var/www/html/E360_UI/>
      Options FollowSymLInks
   </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your apache config is not set to follow symbolic links.

You need to enable the `FollowSymLinks` option in your Apache configuration. You can also enable that in a `.htaccess` file, if the main configuration allows you to override this option.

Place a `.htaccess` file in `/var/www/html`, containing:

`Options +FollowSymLinks`

For that to work, you'll need the correct `Directory`'s `AllowOverride` directive to be set to at least `Options` (`All` would work too, if that's the current value)

Comment: I had FollowSymLinks in the Directory but not AllowOverride All.  When I added that, then it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your document root should not contain Product.

Comment: Ok, I took out /Product and did a sudo service apache2 reload.  Same problem.

Comment: Definitely add the directive `Options FollowSymLinks`. I just tried and I had no issues in accessing symlinks. Also take a look at `error_log` file to see what the actual error is